# Cannot export pem certification for jks

Tags: android, keystore, jks, android-app-signing

I have generated new jks to publish project to upgrade the key. And I am trying to export the pem certificate using command

```
keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keys
tore keystore.jks
```

Getting below errors in android studio terminal

```
'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: keytool is part of the JDK which is usually not in PATH. Thus you have to search the keytool executable and use it's full path.